# Very strange compile time error

Tags: c++, c++11, sfml

I am reading SFML Game Development book and after working through chapter 4 I have [this code](https://github.com/canadien91/tutorial-sfml-game/tree/bulk) and this compiler output:

```
20:17:49: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
g++  -o minimum aircraft.o command_queue.o entity.o game.o main.o player.o scene_node.o sprite_node.o world.o   -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -lsfml-audio -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-network -lsfml-window -lsfml-system 
player.o: In function `std::pair<APlayer::Action const, ACommand>::pair<APlayer::Action const&, 0u>(std::tuple<APlayer::Action const&>&, std::tuple<>&, std::_Index_tuple<0u>, std::_Index_tuple<>)':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:1088: undefined reference to `ACommand::ACommand()'
player.o: In function `std::pair<APlayer::Action const, ACommand>::pair<APlayer::Action&&, 0u>(std::tuple<APlayer::Action&&>&, std::tuple<>&, std::_Index_tuple<0u>, std::_Index_tuple<>)':
/usr/include/c++/4.8/tuple:1088: undefined reference to `ACommand::ACommand()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [minimum] Error 1
20:17:50: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project minimum (kit: Desktop)
When executing step 'Make'
20:17:50: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

My compiler is

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
```

Sorry for a messy question, but I have no idea what's going on. If someone help, I'll make it more clear.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: Those are *linker* errors, and means that the linker can't find the definition for the `ACommand` constructor. You *have* defined it somewhere?

Comment: @chris, thank you for useful information